# Difference between "enquire whether" and "enquire about whether"?

Tags: difference, phrase-meaning

[This answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/134525/50720) claims that **enquire whether** differs from **enquire about whether**. So what does the latter mean?

---

Here are some indications that **enquire about whether** is *correct* usage of some sort.

[Source:](https://books.google.com/books?id=VFIdBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA4&dq=%22enquiry%20about%20whether%22%20linguistics&pg=PA4#v=onepage&q=%22enquiry%20about%20whether%22%20linguistics&f=false) p 4, *Pragmatics and the English Language*,    By [Jonathan Culpeper](http://www.ling.lancs.ac.uk/profiles/jonathan-culpeper) Ph.D  in  Linguistics (Lancaster  Uni), [Associate Prof in Linguistics Michael Haugh](http://research-hub.griffith.edu.au/display/n00880d37015fe35673674c3782ca4a13#background) PhD  (University of Queensland)

> What this joke illustrates is that the whole utterance *Do you have any firearms with you?* can have more than one meaning: is it an **enquiry about whether** the driver has firearms or a request for firearms?

[Source:](https://books.google.com/books?id=Fh1RX6tm_FsC&pg=PA70&dq=%22query+about+whether%22+linguistics&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Srw2VZL4FYmUyQSd-ID4Dw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22query%20about%20whether%22%20linguistics&f=false) p 70, *The Phraseology of Administrative French*,
by [Wendy Anderson](http://www.gla.ac.uk/schools/critical/staff/wendyanderson/) PhD in French linguistics (University of St Andrews)

> In response to a **query about whether** a corpus of written 
>   academic prose in the disciplines of commerce/economics and natural 
>   science/history should be called specific registers or genres, the four linguists who commented all proposed different solutions, ... .

Here's [another](https://books.google.com/books?id=8SwDBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA216&dq=%22inquire+about+whether%22+linguistics&hl=en&sa=X&ei=C7w2VcmTD9W1yAT3z4DIDA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22inquire%20about%20whether%22%20linguistics&f=false) quote by [Prof of Linguistics, Frederick
Newmeyer](http://linguistics.washington.edu/people/frederick-newmeyer).

---

All that said, what distinguishes **enquire whether** and **enquire about whether**?

Comment: Wouldn't this be better split into a question and a self-answer?

Comment: @NathanTuggy No, because I don't understand the difference?

Comment: Well, this really isn't very clearly asked.

Comment: Are you asking if *enquire about whether* is grammatical?

Comment: And is your assumption that PhDs in Linguistics make no grammatical errors? :)

Comment: @NathanTuggy Thanks. Better?

Comment: @TRomano I meant to ask what *enquire about whether* means, compared to *enquire about whether*. No; we're all human, but at least it suggests that it may not be wrong.

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit: A little, but it would still benefit from emphasizing the main question as opposed to emphasizing the apparent correctness or lack thereof.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Thanks. Would you please edit my OP directly?

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit: Well, I've done what I could. I'm still not sure what all the quotes are for exactly, but that should help.

Comment: Your examples show only the noun forms _enquiry_ and _query_. They say nothing in regard to the verb form  _enquire about whether_.

Comment: I would say the difference is that "enquire about whether" has a superfluous "about".

Comment: But that I have only one plus to give @BrianHitchcock's comment!  There's an apples-and-oranges comparison here.  You are asking about a verb and citing examples that use a noun.

Answer (score 1):

"enquire about whether" is a *description* of a question, not a question itself.

In the first example you gave it is being used to distinguish between two separate meanings that could be taken from one question.

Rewritten it could be:

> He asked the driver "Do you have any firearms with you?" Did he mean "are you carrying any firearms?" or was he asking for some?.

Without the "about" in that sentence it would imply a two part question:

> He enquired whether the driver had firearms, or could give him some?

e.g.

> Do you have any firearms? Can I have some?

In the second example you gave it is being used to note that this is a description of a question, not a paraphrase or a direct quotation.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you're asking if *enquire about whether* is grammatical.

It is no more grammatical than *ask about if*, for "if" and "whether" are binary:

... whether she has or she has not; if he is or is not ...

Properly speaking, we ask "if he is", not *about if he is". But speakers can lose sight of the fact that *whether* and *if* yield true|false, and treat these as general interrogatives.

Comment: Yes, your basic point is valid. However people do use "ask about whether" and "ask about if".  It may be seen as justified by some if a clear yes or no answer is not expected. But instead of "Ask him about whether he is going to enter the London Marathom" one might, more grammatically say "Ask him about his intentions as to entering the London Marathon".

Comment: I can certainly find "ask about if" in properly-edited texts, e.g. "ask about if there is a history of previous foot problems" in a medical book. It suggests a more general inquiry than demanding a yes/no answer.

Comment: @Stuart F  I would accept that a certain percentage of speakers say "ask about if" but wouldn't consider that text "properly edited" if the snippet you quoted is indicative.